# Is heroku key set correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a project to heroku. I'm working on win7.

```
$ git push heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.    

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.    

$ heroku keys
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: MYREALEMAIL
Password (typing will be hidden):
=== MYREALEMAIL Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...ol1Ukh0Q== your_email@youremail.com    


$ heroku keys:remove your_email@youremail.com
Removing your_email@youremail.com SSH key... done    

dnir@BCMAM27 /f/EasyPHP-12.1/www/phantomjs123 (master)
$ heroku keys
You have no keys.    

$ heroku keys:add f:/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key f:/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done    

$ heroku keys
=== MYREALEMAIL Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...ol1Ukh0Q== your_email@youremail.com    


$ git push heroku master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.    

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am concerned that the last line should actually say:

```
ssh-rsa ****3NzaC...ol1Uk****== MYACTUALEMAIL
```

Am I correct in this? If so how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check out this article on how to set up ssh keys on heroku.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)

to remove the bad key

```
heroku keys:remove your_email@youremail.com
```

then verify that you have a ssh key

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

if not create one

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"
```

then upload the key to heroku

```
heroku keys:add
```

Comment: what's the key in your .ssh/id_rsa.pub? looks like you need to generate one that isn't your_email@youremail.com, see my edit on creating a new id_rsa.pub with you email

Comment: I ended up using ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "MYEMAIL"to create a new key as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an SSH issue.  I think you'll need to generate a new SSH key based on your email.

If you `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` you'll see "your_email@youremail.com" at the end.  you need to generate a new one with **your** email (or hostname).

Comment: Do I have to generate a new one? I already have one. Please see update.